# deepstreamio - Unable to locate package deepstream.io

Tags: raspbian-jessie, debian

I am trying to install `deepstreamio` in my `raspberrypi` by following [the tutorial here](https://deepstream.io/install/debian/) but cannot get it to work. Basically I do:

```
sudo apt-get install -y deepstream.io
```

and this is what I got:

> Reading package lists... Done
>
> Building dependency tree
>
> Reading state information... Done
>
> E: Unable to locate package deepstream.io
>
> E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'deepstream.io'

Anybody got this to work?

Comment: Have you added the repository to the sources.list as instructed at the start of the tutorial?

Comment: In addition to @joan's point, did you run `sudo apt-get update` between that step and the install? Missing either step is a major pitfall.

Answer (score 2):

deepstream.io only provides Debian packages for x86 architecture, so you'll have to build it from [sources](https://github.com/deepstreamIO/deepstream.io).

Alternatively, you could try the [Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/deepstreamio/deepstream.io-raspbian/) they provide:

```
docker pull deepstreamio/deepstream.io-raspbian
```

Comment: Do that means `raspberrypi` cannot run `deepstream`?